# Charge with Stripe only when specific option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a `Schedule` model with current enum:

```
    enum delivery_option: {
      drop_off: 'drop_off',
      pick_up: 'pick_up'
    }
```

Here's the `Schedules` controller `create` action: (which charges $25 for both options)

```
          def create
            @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)

           amount = 25 * 100
           customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
               email: params[:stripeEmail],
               card: params[:stripeToken]
             )

           charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
               customer: customer.id,
               amount: amount,
               description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
               currency: 'usd'
             )  
           end
```

When User creates a Schedule he can choose either pick_up or drop_off.

I need to charge User for $25 ONLY for `pick_up` option. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you storing delivery_option in `schedule` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to charge to customer for specific option, then yu can put condition like following

Create one method

```
def create
  @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)

  amount = 25 * 100
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
     email: params[:stripeEmail],
     card: params[:stripeToken]
  )

  create_charge(customer, amount, 'Rails Stripe customer', 'usd') if schedule_params[:delivery_option] == "pick_up"
end

private

def create_charge(customer, amt, desc, currency)
  Stripe::Charge.create(
     customer: customer.id,
     amount: amt,
     description: desc,
     currency: currency
   )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out simpler than I thought :)

```
   def create
        @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)


        if schedule_params[:delivery_option] == "pick_up"
           amount = 25 * 100
           customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
               email: params[:stripeEmail],
               card: params[:stripeToken]
             )

             charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
               customer: customer.id,
               amount: amount,
               description: 'Rails Stripe customer',
               currency: 'usd'
             )
        end


        if @schedule.save
           render json: @schedule
        else
           render json: @schedule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
     end
```